# How to use manifest for adding a dll to VC++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, manifest

I am working on a Visual Studio 2010 c++ project where i have 2 DLL with same name but different version. one is build on VS 2010 and another is on VS 2017. Requirement is there is a number of projects link together and placed there binary on a single folder along with statically linked DLL's. i have to put 2017 DLL on this folder and created a folder here where i put 2010 DLL and its path is set on environment variable, among these projects only 1 project is required to use 2010 version DLL, i read on internet its possible if add DLL in these project's manifest file but not get much info how to achieve it is it possible by manifest or any other way. can anybody please help me to get rid out of that.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/523f3e64-aa12-4fcc-bb7f-3aade9b188ac/how-do-i-tell-application-manifest-file-to-use-a-dll-in-current-directory-?forum=vclanguage

Comment: Thanks Jeaninez but I tried this problem is i am using windows 7 and in windows 7 <file> tag not supported in manifest file:  
    <file name="msvcr80d.dll"></file>
Here is the sxstrace: ERROR: Line 1: The element file appears as a child of element urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1^dependentAssembly which is not supported by this version of Windows.

Comment: You could try to build C/C++ Side-by-side Assemblies.One or several related DLLs can be repackaged into a side-by-side assembly with a corresponding assembly manifest, which describes which files form the assembly as well as the dependence of the assembly on other side-by-side assemblies.I suggest you could refer to the links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-c-cpp-side-by-side-assemblies?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/understanding-manifest-generation-for-c-cpp-programs?view=vs-2019